# How to decrease GPU Inference time and Increase its Utilization?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

We ran inference over 1280*720 RGB images using Faster RCNN from TensorFlow model zoo, trained over the COCO dataset and got some results

- Test case 1:

  Created a tf session using `tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph())`

  > Batch Size = 4, GPU use = 100% (as default)
  >
  > Time Taken for inference of 4 images = 0.32 secs
- Test case 2:

  > Then we restricted the GPU usage for each TF session to a fraction using gpu_options

  `gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.40)`
  `tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph(), config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))`

  > For a batch size of 2, the time taken for inference was 0.16secs, which is understandable because this is linear.
- Test case 3:

  Ran 2 instances of inferences as two different python processes. Here, both the batch sizes were 2.

  The inference slowed down considerably, and the final value was 0.32secs, which is same as the case of one process running inference over the batch size of 4.

  > Batch Size = 2, GPU use = 40%, Processes = 2
  >
  > Time Taken = 0.32 secs

Hence, in Case 1 and Case 3, time taken is the same.

Q.1 Is there any way to reduce the time taken?

Q.2 Where is the bottleneck? In 1st case also, it doesn’t seem that the entire GPU memory is being utilised. Therefore, we had thought that if we were to divide the inference into two, more efficient utilisation of resources could be done. Where are we going wrong in our understanding?

Comment: How are you feeding the data into your model? In my experience the bottlenecks usually arise in any data read / preprocessing steps before, meaning the GPU is many waiting around doing nothing

Comment: @Karl We are using two processes here. The producer is taking images from a camera and feeding it to the consumer without any preprocessing. The producer here is very Fast as compared to the consumer. The consumer takes the fed image and runs inference on it.